# Lower opacity of other text if it's not mouseover in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a project where I need to hover on a text which will not make it transparent but the rest of the text will.

In my code, I have a table where each row has its own text. I know how to set an ID attribute when you hover over the text but I couldn't figure out how to make the non selected text transparent.

The idea is that the ID, "test", will not turn the text transparent, any text that does not have the ID will turn transparent.

I would definitely prefer a Javascript solution.

Here's my window.onload code:

```
window.onload = function () {
let selectedRow = document.querySelector("tr");
selectedRow.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
    createID(selectedRow);
    transparent(selectedRow, createID(selectedRow));
}, false)

selectedRow.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
    nonTransparent(selectedRow);
}, false);
}
```

And here are my functions outside the window.onload:

```
function createID(elem){
    elem.setAttribute("id", "test");
}

function transparent(elem, id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        if (elem[i] !== id) {
            elem[i].style.opacity = "0.25";
        }
    }
}

function nonTransparent(elem) {
    for (let i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].style.opacity = "1";
    }
}
```

And here's my table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Country</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>United Kingdom</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>United States of America</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If I gather your code correct you want to make each non hovered `tr` transparent, which is easy doable in css. Also your `createID()` will provide the same `id` multiple times, which is *not an ideal* thing. Furthermore you are passing `undefined` as second argument to `transparent()` due to `createID()` not returning anything.

Comment: What is the status of this?

Answer (score 0):

Not certain, but it looks like this is what you want to end up with. `css` only solution.

```css
table:hover tr{
  opacity: 0.25
}

table tr:hover{
  opacity: 1
}

table tr td:hover{
  background-color: #e6e6fa
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Age</td>
    <td>Country</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>United Kingdom</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jane Doe</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>United States of America</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

Your JavaScript has too many flaws to actually start commenting on it.